# Aurigma Image Upload - Can you upload multiple grouped sets of images?

Tags: .net, image, file-upload, aurigma

I am basically looking at uploading a batch of images, they will be categorised into different groups.

For example:

3 images for photoshoot1

4 images for photoshoot2

1 image for photoshoot3

I want the 3 (or however many) groups of images to be separated visually and have a drop down option under each image.

All the images and relevant meta (from the drop down) should be uploaded from a main upload button which will then upload them one at a time.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the [Aurigma Image Pro](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/) control?

I have looked through there [API](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/) and I can't see anything. Is anyone familiar with this?